# How to reflect the same results as from sklearn's TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to build the TfidfVectorizer from scratch and I have built almost the same vectorizer as sklearn's but I am not able to get the same tf-idf scores as TfidfVectorizer.

Here is my code:

```
def vocab(corpus):
    entire_corpus = ' '.join([i for i in corpus]).split()
    values = Counter(entire_corpus)
    return dict(values)


def tfidf(corpus, vocab):
    row = 0
    vocabs = vocab(corpus)
    for sentence in corpus:
        col = 0
        word_freq = Counter(sentence.split())
        for word, freq in word_freq.items():
            tf = freq/len(sentence)
            n = vocabs.get(word, -1)
            if n != -1:
                idf = 1.0 + math.log((len(corpus)+1)/(n+1))
            print((row, col), tf*idf)
            col = col+1
        row = row + 1


vocabs = vocab(corpus)
tfidf(corpus, vocabs)
```

output for the first line is

(0, 0) 0.038461538461538464

(0, 1) 0.038461538461538464

(0, 2) 0.038461538461538464

(0, 3) 0.05810867783715349

(0, 4) 0.038461538461538464

Whereas output from sklearn's TfIDFvectorizer is

(0, 8)  0.38408524091481483

(0, 6)  0.38408524091481483

(0, 3)  0.38408524091481483

(0, 2)  0.5802858236844359

(0, 1)  0.46979138557992045

can you tell me where I am getting it wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def tfidf_vectorizer(corpus):

    terms = list(set(' '.join([i for i in corpus]).split()))

    terms.sort()

    mat = np.zeros((len(corpus), len(terms)))

    for i in range(len(corpus)):

        tf = Counter(corpus[i].split())

        for j in range(len(terms)):

            df = len([document for document in corpus if terms[j] in document])

            idf = 1.0 + np.log((len(corpus) + 1) / (df + 1))

            mat[i, j] = tf[terms[j]] * idf

    return (terms, mat)

corpus = ['this is the first document',
          'this document is the second document',
          'this one is the third']

# manual calculation
vectorizer_1 = tfidf_vectorizer(corpus)

terms_1 = vectorizer_1[0]
matrix_1 = vectorizer_1[1]

# scikit-learn calculation
vectorizer_2 = TfidfVectorizer(norm=None).fit(corpus)

terms_2 = vectorizer_2.get_feature_names()
matrix_2 = vectorizer_2.transform(corpus).toarray()
```

```
print(pd.DataFrame(data=matrix_1, columns=terms_1))

   document     first   is       one    second  the     third  this
0  1.287682  1.693147  1.0  0.000000  0.000000  1.0  0.000000   1.0
1  2.575364  0.000000  1.0  0.000000  1.693147  1.0  0.000000   1.0
2  0.000000  0.000000  1.0  1.693147  0.000000  1.0  1.693147   1.0
```

```
print(pd.DataFrame(data=matrix_2, columns=terms_2))

   document     first   is       one    second  the     third  this
0  1.287682  1.693147  1.0  0.000000  0.000000  1.0  0.000000   1.0
1  2.575364  0.000000  1.0  0.000000  1.693147  1.0  0.000000   1.0
2  0.000000  0.000000  1.0  1.693147  0.000000  1.0  1.693147   1.0
```

Comment: Why are you using term frequency as only the number occurrence in a string whereas the term frequency of a word defined as the number of occurrence of a word divided by the total number of words in a document?